# CSharpCodeProvider how to reference current assembly

Tags: reference, file-not-found, csharpcodeprovider

I'm trying to dynamically compile code using CSharpCodeProvider. In the referenced assemblies, I'm adding a reference parameter for typeof(Program).Assembly.CodeBase), as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657117/referencing-current-assembly-with-compilerparameters), but it doesn't work. I still get an error saying

```
error CS0006: Metadata file 'file:///C:/Code/MyProject/bin/MyProject.DLL' could not be found;
```

A file by that name does exist - the only difference is that the file extension shows lowercase in file explorer (".dll"), but otherwise, the filename from the error message matches the name and path of the dll I want to reference.

Any idea why the compiler would fail to see the referenced dll in this case?
Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
        CompilerResults result = null;
        CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters();
        parms.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parms.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parms.OutputAssembly = "MyOutputAssembly";
        parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(Program).Assembly.CodeBase); // Reference the current assembly

        // Lock because CSharpCodeProvider can only compile the code once per time slot
        lock (lockCompile)
        {
            using (CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
            {
                result = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parms, new string[] { code.ToString() });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try using `typeof(Program).Assembly.Location` instead of `.CodeBase`. The `.Location` property on the assembly will return a straight-up path, whereas `.CodeBase` returns the location in URI form. I'm not sure but I think there might be scenarios related to loading remotely-hosted code where `.Location` doesn't give you anything and `.CodeBase` might give e.g. an `http` URI, but in your scenario, it sounds like your assembly is always going to be local, so you should always have a valid `.Location` value. :-)

Comment: Done, and thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks! That worked - if you add as an answer I'll mark as answer - and retrieved a very different path from .CodeBase - CodeBase retrieved the bin folder location, while Location got a temp directory: C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\myIISDirName\\65307448\\ec575f43\\assembly\\dl3\\d46288d9\\3e71eb5a_c275d201\\MyProject.dll. This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864484/getting-the-path-of-the-current-assembly) seems to suggest that .Location pulls the address prior to shadow copying, and makes me a bit confused over when Location is safe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `typeof(Program).Assembly.Location` instead of `.CodeBase`. The `.Location` property on the assembly will return a straight-up path to the actual file that is loaded, whereas `.CodeBase` returns the caonical location in URI form. I'm not sure but I think there might be scenarios related to loading remotely-hosted code where `.Location` doesn't give you anything and `.CodeBase` might give e.g. an `http` URI, but in your scenario, it sounds like your assembly is always going to be local, so you should always have a valid `.Location` value. :-)

Comment: In the end I'm going with new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath per the advantages posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864484/getting-the-path-of-the-current-assembly, but in any case the "marked" answer above also worked and got me there!